# Python program not exiting in except block

Tags: python, exception

I have a python program that does some data collection. In the collection function, I have to first check that the network connection is still alive, and exit(1) if it has been disconnected like so:

```
try:
    collect_data()
except:
    logging.error("Connection dropped. Exiting program.")
    exit(1)
```

The problem is that the program is not exiting. I know that the except block executes because the log file shows the "Connection dropped." error. Any idea how this could happen?

Using Python 2.7

Comment: Are you sure that `exit()` is `sys.exit()`?

Comment: You're using a blanket `except` here. That's a bad idea, and it suggests that you might be doing the same thing elsewhere in your code. Any other blanket `except`s on the stack will intercept the `SystemExit` exception and cancel the exit.

Comment: what happens instead? did another catch all `except` block stop the program from exiting?

Comment: Is this code implemented in the main thread? Python documentation states that _Since exit() ultimately “only” raises an exception, it will only exit the process when called from the main thread, and the exception is not intercepted._ See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @user2357112 and all others who commented for figuring this out. Turns out I was using too many blanket except statements and two things were happening:

1. Depending on when the exit() was called, it sometimes got caught by other except blocks and got ignored.
2. Sometimes when I killed the program with a Ctrl-C KeyboardInterrupt from within collect_data() it was being caught by the above except block by accident (which I hadn't noticed before because of issue #1).

Corrected code should be something like this:

```
try:
    collect_data()
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("Connection dropped. Exiting program.")
    sys.exit(1)
```

This fixed the issue I was having. Thanks again SO for saving me from my own stupidity.